# A strange sizeof() bug occured on DevC++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, dev-c++

I know I shouldn't use Dev-C++ but it's mandatory in school so I can't do anything about it.

Topic is pointers in C/C++ and a bug occurred while measuring the length of an integer array. See the code below:

```
// POINTER
# include<iostream>
# include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    //neues Feld anlegen
    int *a = new int[5];

    a[0] = 12;
    a[1] = 5;
    a[2] = 43;
    a[3] = -12;
    a[4] = 100;
    // Feld füllen

    for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(a);i++){
            cout<<a[i]<<"\n"<<endl;
            }
    cout<<sizeof(a);
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

The sizeof() returns 4 and not 5...Any ideas?

Comment: My first idea is that unless you are God, you should never assume that unexpected behaviour is someone else's fault, least of all a "compiler bug". The only right question to ask is "Where do I fail to understand C and C++ in this piece of code?"

Comment: "so I can't do anything about it." I feel your pain, but you could at least point your instructors to [the information here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dev-c%2b%2b/info). :)

Comment: A bug in sizeof is almost impossible for a compiler, it means almost everything is broken if sizeof is broken! Bugs in compilers are rare, Microsoft and GCC have some but only if you do really weird stuff, especially with templates!

Comment: **arrays are not pointers; pointers are not arrays**. Read the [comp.lang.c faq](http://c-faq.com/) starting with section 6 :)

Comment: Just to make one thing clear: `sizeof(a)` wouldn't be 5, even if the type of `a` was actually `int[5]`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is not a bug because its returning the size of `a` itself (which is of type `int*` - 4 bytes on a 32 bit build), not the length of the array.

*Please note* - others say that the size is dependent on the operating system, which is half-true. It really depends on the build. `sizeof` is a compile-time construct.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you shouldn't think that the culprit of a "strange" behaviour is the compiler: most of the time the bug is yours.

In fact, your `sizeof` instruction tells you what's the size of an `int*` and that's by design, so it's not a compiler's fault but your misunderstanding. There's no way to use `sizeof` to tell the size of a dynamically allocated array.

Answer (score 2):

a in this case is a pointer, a size of a pointer depends on the compiler.

You are doing sizeof(int*).
Indeed you are using a 32 bit compiler, and for your compiler\system pointers are 32 bits.

You cannot get the size of an object allocated with new from its pointer, sizeof is evaluated at compile time, not at runtime.

To obtain the size of the array you should do...

```
int a[5]; // Array allocated in stack, we can use sizeof.
std::cout << (sizeof(a) / sizeof(int));
```

sizeof returns the size in bytes not the number of elements on an array.

That code is equivalent to write

```
std::cout << (sizeof(int[5]) / sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 1):

sizeof does not tell you an array size.  It tells you the size of a datatype, in this case, an int*, which on your platform is 4 bytes.  It will always be 4 regardless of the number of array elements.

Comment: In case he would have declared `char a[5]`, `sizeof()` would have *returned an array size*, in that case the expected 5. Anyhow `sizeof()` does *not* return the number of elements in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Local variable `a` is a pointer type (`int*`). Pointer size is 4 bytes in 32bit operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

```
int* a;
cout<<sizeof(a);
```

is equivalent to:

```
cout<<sizeof(int*);
```

Which is variable, depending on the platform. On most x32 platforms, it will be 4 bytes, and on x64 platforms 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

also the misconception that you have here is that

```
int a* = new int[5];
```

means that you are declaring a as a pointer to an array of `int` types. This is infact not the case.

`int a*`  means that you are declaring a pointer to an `int`.

`new int[5]` means that you are allocating memory space for 5 `int` types.

`int a* = new int[5];` means that you are allocating memory for storing 5 ints and setting the int point a to point to the first element.

If you had declared an array:

```
int a[5];  // an array of 5 ints
```

then you could:

```
for (int i=0; i< (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])); i++)
{
  cout<<a[i]<<"\n"<<end1;
}  

cout<< sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

easier way to do what you want:

```
    #define NumberOfInts 5

    int* a = new int[NumberOFInts];

    for(int i = 0; i<NumberOfInts; i++){ 
    ....
    }
```

I'm not sure if this is generally considered "good style" but it will fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

You just get the size of a **pointer** but not the size of the **array**. If you compile this code as 64-bit, you will get another result.

I usually use the code below:

```
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 5;

int a* = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
{
    // Do something.
}

// Release
if (a)
{
    delete[] a;
    a = NULL;
}
```